# How does this step up converter work?

Tags: power-supply

Just bought an adapter to use an ATX psu as replacement to an HP proprietary one. It has a step-up module which converts the ATX 5vsb to 12vsb. I just want to know what the extra 12v input is for and if it can be removed. It seems like it passes the 12v rail together with the step-up output by a diode. Thank you[image: 5vsb to 12vsb step-up converter]

Comment: We don't even know what is an input and what an output on this board...

Comment: Other than that, the quality of the solder joint on the top left corner of your board is a real issue.

Comment: Sorry. Input to output is right to left. Solder is pretty good on the other side. Will resolder just to be sure.

Comment: What's on the other side of the board?  What does the user manual say to do with the +12V connection?

Comment: Just the copper traces. It doesnt have any documentation. I just wanna know how the extra 12v input would affect the 12vsb of the ATX psu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a diode-OR function.  I would assume the connection is in case there's already a 12V standby present in the system.

Assuming there are no new connections on the backside, of course.

But the real answer is: read the manual.  If there's no manual, guide, spec sheet... then it's anyone's guess how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Thank you Tim. After searching the term it finally made sense. It might be used to supply more current when the 12vsb from the converter isnt enough assuming the system is on?